# Global variable space that is shared between chrome app windows

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Is there a way to create a global variable space between different windows of the same app? Accessing the main window's variables is also acceptable, I can bind angular on them.

Comment: `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function callback)` will give you access to the `window` object of the event page of the app from any other window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function callback) will give you access to the window object of the event page of the app from any other window. - [rsanchez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1507998/rsanchez).

Comment: BTW, it not only for event-pages, but for background-pages in general (i.e. works for both persistent and non-persistent background-pages).

Comment: Think of the background page as the main() for your app, if you're familiar with Java or C. Windows come and go, but the background page remains. (Disclaimer: they go away, too, and you can have multiple background pages, but it's an accurate way to describe them.)